# How to get Distinct values from all columns of a table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, distinct

I want to retrieve record for distinct value with it's ID ,Table is like this ::

```
ID     Name
1      Soap
2      eridu
3      Soap
4      rewfig
5      Soap
```

Now I want result:

```
ID  Name
1   Soap
2   eridu
3   rewfig
```

I use like this: [Table Name is tblRecord

```
select Distinct(Name) ,ID
  from tblRecord
 where Name in (select Distinct(Name) 
                  from tblRecord
               )
```

Comment: isn't the ID  of `rewfig` = 4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT ID, Name
FROM 
(
    SELECT ID, Name,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER  (PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY ID ASC) rn
    FROM tableName
) s
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY ID
```

- [**See SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/576a6/3)

but the simpliest Solution if you have no other column is

```
SELECT MIN(ID) ID, Name
FROM tableName
GROUP BY Name
```

- [**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/576a6/4)

Comment: I try this this will give me proper result...SELECT ID, Name
FROM 
(
    SELECT ID, Name,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER  (PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY ID ASC) rn
    FROM tableName
) s
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY ID

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT Id, Name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Id) row_num
  FROM Table
)
SELECT Id, Name
FROM CTE
WHERE row_num = 1;
```

This will give you:

```
ID  NAME
2   eridu
4   rewfig
1   Soap
```

If you want to get the exact output like what you did in your question. You will need to generate a new ranking number for the result. Try to use `DENSE_RANK()` function like so:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT Id, Name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Name) row_num
  FROM Table1
)
SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY Name) ID, Name
FROM CTE
WHERE row_num = 1;
```

This should give you the exact desired result set:

```
ID  NAME
1   eridu
2   rewfig
3   Soap
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e4abb/5)